# Setting a bool if a value in List<Struct> is equal to a given value

Tags: c#, .net, struct

The code below will return true or false based on the last **Items ID** in the **sList**. I'm stumped beyond that point, what I wanted to find out was if any one `sList[i].getID = 1` then it would set the `bool value = true` but if all of the values under `sList[i].getID = 0` then it would set the `bool value = false`. I feel like it's an easy answer but my brain feels quite cloudy right now.

```
public Class Data 
{
     public struct Struct
     {
         public Struct(string s, bool b, Vector2 v, int i) 
             : this() 
          {
              this.text = s;
              this.tf = b;
              this.ID = i
              this.seg = v;
          }

         private String text { get; set; }
         public String getText { get { return text; } }
         private bool tf { get; set }
         public bool getTF { get { return tf; } }
         private Vector2 seg { get; set; }
         public Vector2 getSeg { get { return seg; } }
         private int ID { get; set; }
         public int getID { get { return ID; } }
     }
}
```

**Some other class:**

```
List<Data.Struct> sList = new List<Class.Struct>();
bool value = false;

sList.Add(new Data.Struct("Hello", false, new Vector2(150, 150), 0));
sList.Add(new Data.Struct("Cruel", true, new Vector2(150, 150), 1));
sList.Add(new Data.Struct("World", true, new Vector2(150, 150), 0));

for(int i = 0; i < sList.Count; i++)
{
     if(sList[i].getID == 1)
     {
          value = true;
     } 
     else if(sList[i].getID == 0)
     {
          value = false;
     }
}
```

Comment: `value = sList.Any(d => d.getId == 1);`? Use `System.Linq` namespace.

Comment: Use Linq, or extract a method out of it and add a `return` statement, or add a `break` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a `for` loop, you need to set the flag to `false` first and then set it to `true` only if you encounter a `1`. Currently, you're overwriting your value on each pass.

```
value = false;
for (int i = 0; i < sList.Count; i++)
{
    if (sList[i].getID == 1)
    {
        value = true;
    }
}
```

That way, once it's set to `true`, even if any of the following values is a `0`, it won't reset to `false`.

You can also use a `break` statement after the `true` to shorten the loop's execution time. Since you really don't have a lot of data, it's pretty much up to what you prefer.

---

As a cleaner alternative, you can use LINQ's [`Any`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337697%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
bool value = sList.Any(s => s.getID == 1);
```

This is pretty much as it reads, it will return `true` if any value in your list have a ID equals to one.

You could also use a less clean-y negative [`All`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb548541%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
bool value = !sList.All(s => s.getID == 0);
```

That one is the inverse, and less obvious.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Data.Struct> sList = new List<Class.Struct>();

sList.Add(new Data.Struct("Hello", false, new Vector2(150, 150), 0));
sList.Add(new Data.Struct("Cruel", true, new Vector2(150, 150), 1));
sList.Add(new Data.Struct("World", true, new Vector2(150, 150), 0));

bool value = sList.Any(s => s.getID == 1);
```

You may need to add a `using` directive at the top of the file for this to work.

If you cannot use the `Any()` method for some reason, do this:

```
List<Data.Struct> sList = new List<Class.Struct>();

sList.Add(new Data.Struct("Hello", false, new Vector2(150, 150), 0));
sList.Add(new Data.Struct("Cruel", true, new Vector2(150, 150), 1));
sList.Add(new Data.Struct("World", true, new Vector2(150, 150), 0));

bool value = false;
foreach(var s in sList) 
{ 
    if (s.getId == 1) 
    {
       value = true;  
       break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should break the loop when you get `true`, and if you get true in value after loop it means there was atleast one `getID == 1`. As you are not breaking the loop the decision is made on last element of the collection and any true value is over-written by the last item getID

```
for(int i = 0; i < sList.Count; i++)
{
     if(sList[i].getID == 1)
     {
          value = true;
          break;
     }        
}

if(value)
{
    //There was at least one element having true  for  getID 
}
else
{
   //There was not element having true for  getID 
}
```

If you can use linq, you can use `Any`

```
bool value = sList.Any(item => item.getID == 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's only returning the comparison for the last item in the list because it keeps iterating the list after it finds the item it wants.  And each time it loops over the next item, the value of `value` is overwritten.  So only the last value of `value` is retained.

You could "exit the loop" when you find a match, something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < sList.Count; i++)
{
     if(sList[i].getID == 1)
     {
          value = true;
          break; // exit the loop
     } 
     else if(sList[i].getID == 0)
     {
          value = false;
     }
}
```

But there's actually an easier way.  The `.Any()` extension method on enumerable collections will return `true` if any item matches the supplied condition.  Something like this:

```
value = sList.Any(x => x.getID == 1);
```